# In Pandas, how to convert a string to a datetime object with milliseconds?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a column of event's timestamp in my dataframe, looks like "2016-06-10 18:58:25:675", the last 3 digits are milliseconds, is there a efficient way to transform this column to a Pandas datatime type?

When I try:

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-06-10 18:57:35:317')
```

An error occurs saying "Unknown string format".

Comment: Is it because the standard format is `35.317`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-06-10 18:57:35:317', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
```

You can look up datetime formats [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Awesome! We answered at the same time! Well played, Sir

Comment: Millisecond resolution ;)

Comment: This should be an example in the docs!

Answer (score 4):

Normally there is a period / full-stop between the seconds and microseconds.

Since your data does not have that you can specify how your data is formatted:

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-06-10 18:57:35:317', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```